# Full Calendar listDay error: spec.class is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

According to the fullCalendar documentation there are nine different views available. Five of these views have demos while the others do not. Becuase the monthly view is not responsive I am interested in having the view change into the dayList view when on mobile. The default view is currently month but when setting this to `defaultView: listDay` as a property of the plugin I get the following error:

`spec.class is not a constructor`

I am using version 2.7.2 with the correct style sheets from a CDN. I am most interested in having my calendar display similar to the calendar found at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list_view/intro/

Here is what my code looks like to generate my calendar.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'listDay',
    eventColor: '#9ADCC6', 
    eventTextColor: '#000',
    header: {
    left: 'title',
    center: '',
    right: 'today prev, next',
},
displayEventEnd: true, 
buttonIcons: {
    prev: 'left-single-arrow',

},
eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view){

    $('.myModal3 .title').text(event.title);
    $('.myModal3 .date').text(event.start.format('MMM Do YYYY @ h:mm:ss a'));
    $('.myModal3 .modal-body').text(event.desc);
     $('.myModal3 .modal-body').append(" <a href='"+event.link+"' target='_blank'>Learn More</a>");

    $('.myModal3').css('display','block');
    $('.myModal3.fade').css('opacity', '1');
},      
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/events-iu-rss/calendar.asp',
        data: {
            start: start.unix(),
            end: end.unix()
        },
        success: function(doc) {
            var events = [];
            // e = key, a = value
            $(doc).find('event').each(function(e, a) {

                   var time = $(a).find('start-date-time').text(); 
                   //Wed, 16 Sep 2015 10:00:00 EDT
                   var endTime = $(a).find('end-date-time').text(); 
                   var formatEndTime = moment(endTime).format(); 
                    var formatTime = moment(time).format(); 
                    //console.log(a); 
                    //console.log(formatTime.substr(11));
                    //console.log(formatEndTime.substr(11));
                    html = $.parseHTML( $(a).find('description').text() );
                 //stripping out first 11 characters of formatTime and formatEndTime, comparing the two times, and setting allDay value based on result
                if((formatTime.substr(11))==(formatEndTime.substr(11))){
                    events.push({
                    title: $(a).find('summary').text(),
                    link: $(a).find('event-url').text(),
                    start: formatTime,
                    end: formatEndTime,
                    allDay: true,
                    desc: $($.parseHTML( $(a).find('description').text() )).html()
                });
                }
                else{
                    events.push({
                    title: $(a).find('summary').text(),
                    link: $(a).find('event-url').text(),
                    start: formatTime,
                    end: formatEndTime,
                    allDay: false,
                    desc: $($.parseHTML( $(a).find('description').text() )).html()
                });
                }

            });
            callback(events);
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: [List View](https://fullcalendar.io/blog/2016/09/feature-packed-releases/) was only added in FullCalendar v3.0.

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: I just updated to FullCalendar v3.0